# isSame meridiem with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there a way to check if two dates have the same meridiem (am/pm) with moment.js?

In the docs the [isSame](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) function provides examples of testing for day, month, etc., but not for meridiem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing built in to do that exact comparison, but you could just format both moments as just the meridiem token (a) and compare the result.

```
moment().format('a') === moment('2016-01-01T11:00').format('a')
```

This has the advantage of actually working with any locale. In some locales, they have more Meridiem indicators than just AM/PM. Take for example Azerbaijani:

```
moment.locale('az')

moment('2016-01-01T02:00:00').format('hh a')
"02 gecə"

moment('2016-01-01T05:00:00').format('hh a')
"05 səhər"

moment('2016-01-01T13:00:00').format('hh a')
"01 gündüz"

moment('2016-01-01T18:00:00').format('hh a')
"06 axşam"
```

Looking in the source code, I also see this for Belarusian, Bengali, Tibetan, and the list goes on and on.

If you want a full list, go to the locales folder in Moment's source:
https://github.com/moment/moment/tree/develop/src/locale

Within every locale, you will see a meridiem function. This defines the behavior you get for that token.

If you don't want this behavior, and you want your code to always just run as 'before noon' or 'after noon', you can always just quick flip a clone of the moment back into the default locale:

```
moment('2016-01-01T18:00:00').clone().locale('en').format('a')
```

Comment: Thanks!  This works well.  My Wikipedia skills could not turn up a third meridiem other than am or pm.  Examples?

Comment: Edited. I had to look in our source myself. The source should be quite reliable though. Almost every locale has had multiple native speakers proofread it.

Comment: This is a great & helpful answer and also really educational.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to exist in moment.js indeed. Shouldn't be that hard though:

```
Math.floor(time1.hour()/12) == Math.floor(time2.hour()/12);
```

If you are planning to use this a lot and want to make things easier on yourself, you could even add it to Moment yourself (I'll probably receive some strong arguments against extending third party libraries, but it is just so convenient...)

Something like this:

```
moment.prototype.isSameMeredian = function(compareWith) {
    if (! moment.isMoment(compareWith)) {
        return false; // or throw an error or something
    }
    return Math.floor(this.hour()/12) == Math.floor(compareWith.hour()/12)
}
```

and you could use it like this:

```
var time1 = moment();
var time2 = moment().subtract(12, 'hours');
var time3 = moment().add(5, 'minutes');

console.log(time1.isSameMeredian(time2), time1.isSameMeredian(time3));
```

This should log `false` `true`, except between 11:55 and 12:00, where the second outcome should be false as well for obvious reasons.